# How do you setup AWS Cloudfront to provide custom access to S3 bucket with signed cookies using wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cookies, amazon-cloudfront, signed

AWS Cloudfront with Custom Cookies using Wildcards in Lambda Function:

The problem:
On AWS s3 Storage to provide granular access control the preferred method is to use AWS Cloudfront with signed URL's.

```
Here is a good example how to setup cloudfront a bit old though, so you need to use the recommended settings not
the legacy and copy the generated policy down to S3.
https://medium.com/@himanshuarora/protect-private-content-using-cloudfront-signed-cookies-fd9674faec3

I have provided an example below on how to create one of these signed URL's using Python and the newest libraries.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html

However this requires the creation of a signed URL for each item in the S3 bucket. To give wildcard access to a
directory of items in the S3 bucket you need use what is called a custom Policy. I could not find any working examples
of this code using Python, many of the online expamples have librarys that are depreciated. But attached is a working example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html

I had trouble getting the python cryptography package to work by building the lambda function on an Amazon Linux 2
instance on AWS EC2. Always came up with an error of a missing library. So I use Klayers for AWS and worked
https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/tree/master/deployments.

A working example for cookies for a canned policy (Means only a signed URL specific for each S3 file)
https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/s3-cloudfront-to-deliver-static-asset
```

Answer (score 0):

My code for cookies for a custom policy (Means a single policy statement with URL wildcards etc). You must use the Cryptology
package type examples but the private_key.signer function was depreciated for a new private_key.sign function with an extra
argument.  https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing

````
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    import base64
    import datetime


    class CFSigner:
        def sign_rsa(self, message):
            private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
                self.keyfile, password=None, backend=default_backend()
            )

            signature = private_key.sign(message.encode(
                "utf-8"), padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())
            return signature

        def _sign_string(self, message, private_key_file=None, private_key_string=None):
            if private_key_file:
            self.keyfile = open(private_key_file, "rb").read()
            elif private_key_string:
              self.keyfile = private_key_string.encode("utf-8")
            return self.sign_rsa(message)

        def _url_base64_encode(self, msg):
            msg_base64 = base64.b64encode(msg).decode("utf-8")
            msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace("+", "-")
            msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace("=", "_")
            msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace("/", "~")
            return msg_base64

        def generate_signature(self, policy, private_key_file=None):
            signature = self._sign_string(policy, private_key_file)
            encoded_signature = self._url_base64_encode(signature)
            return encoded_signature

        def create_signed_cookies2(self, url, private_key_file, keypair_id, expires_at):
            policy = self.create_custom_policy(url, expires_at)
            encoded_policy = self._url_base64_encode(
                policy.encode("utf-8"))

            signature = self.generate_signature(
                policy, private_key_file=private_key_file)

            cookies = {
                "CloudFront-Policy": encoded_policy,
                "CloudFront-Signature": signature,
                "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id": keypair_id,
            }
            return cookies

        def sign_to_cloudfront(object_url, expires_at):
              cf = CFSigner()
              url = cf.create_signed_url(
                url=object_url,
                keypair_id="xxxxxxxxxx",
                expire_time=expires_at,
                private_key_file="xxx.pem",
              )
              return url

        def create_signed_cookies(self, object_url, expires_at):
              cookies = self.create_signed_cookies2(
                url=object_url,
                private_key_file="xxx.pem",
                keypair_id="xxxxxxxxxx",
                expires_at=expires_at,
              )
              return cookies

        def create_custom_policy(self, url, expires_at):
            return (
                '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"'
                + url
                + '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'
                + str(round(expires_at.timestamp()))
                + "}}}]}"
            )

        def lambda_handler(event, context):
          response = event["Records"][0]["cf"]["response"]
          headers = response.get("headers", None)
          cf = CFSigner()
          path = "https://www.example.com/*"
          expire = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
          signed_cookies = cf.create_signed_cookies(path, expire)
          headers["set-cookie"] = [{
            "key": "set-cookie",
            "value": "CloudFront-Policy={signed_cookies.get('CloudFront-Policy')}"
          }]
          headers["Set-cookie"] = [{
            "key": "Set-cookie",
            "value": "CloudFront-Signature={signed_cookies.get('CloudFront-Signature')}",
          }]
          headers["Set-Cookie"] = [{
            "key": "Set-Cookie",
            "value": "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id={signed_cookies.get('CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id')}",
          }]
          print(response)
          return response ```
````